How to use layout and provider in the same page?
I have provider which makes a request to the server to refresh a token and has some values. Also I have a simple layout with a sidebar. I wanna use them only in one route. Idk where to add the layout and I've already used Outlet in the provider
Provider:
export const AuthProvider: FC = () => {
  const [isUserLoged, setIsUserLoged] = useState(false)
  const [isAppReady, setIsAppReady] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    AuthClient.post("/refresh").then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
      const {accessToken, accessTokenExpiration} = res.data;

      inMemoryJWT.setToken(accessToken, accessTokenExpiration)

      setIsAppReady(true)
      setIsUserLoged(true)
    }).catch((err) => {
      setIsAppReady(true)
      toast.error(err.response.data.error)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePersistedLogOut = (e: StorageEvent) => {
      if(e.key === config.LOGOUT_STORAGE_KEY) {
        inMemoryJWT.deleteToken()
        setIsUserLoged(false)
      }
    }

    return window.addEventListener("storage", handlePersistedLogOut)
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAppReady,
        isUserLoged,
      }}
    >

    <Outlet />
    
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

Routing:
export const Routers: FC = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<AuthProvider />}>
                    <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
                </Route>

                <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />

                <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage message="Страница не найдена!" status={404} />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}



There is really no need to "do it all in one route" when layout routes can be pathless. Pathless routes only contribute to the UI, nothing to the URL path.
A trivial solution is to use separate layout routes for separate concerns.
Example:
export const Routers: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AuthProvider />}> // <-- pathless
          <Route element={<Layout />}>     // <-- pathless
            <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
          </Route>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<ErrorPage message="Страница не найдена!" status={404} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

If you have layout components that are commonly used together then you can abstract these into a single layout.
Example:
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  ...

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAppReady,
        isUserLoged,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    {children}
    ...

  );
};

const AuthLayout = () => (
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Outlet />
      </Layout>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
);

export const Routers: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}> // <-- pathless
          <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<ErrorPage message="Страница не найдена!" status={404} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};


Is there a reason you can't just do this:
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<AuthProvider><Layout><div>Home</div></Layout></AuthProvider>}>
</Route>

And then use the children prop in both the provider and layout components?
